# Nitrous desktop error warning

Tags: nitrousio

I'm on Windows. My Nitrous desktop app wont sync files. It says
"Error Warning the previous run of unison terninated in a dangerous state."

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The file transferring may not have completed properly. Try restarting the Nitrous Desktop app and try again.

If you run the app from the command line then you should see a full log message details on which files it is having issues with. If the app continuously displays this error then you may want to try removing the files which are causing the warning.

Here is a full explanation via [Yahoo Groups](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/unison-users/conversations/topics/9248):

> There is a small window of danger while Unison is finishing
>   transferring a file, when the old file has been moved to a temporary
>   location but the new file has not been moved where it belongs. This
>   message is telling you that Unison got interrupted just at this moment
>   the last time it ran. You should check the file it's warning you
>   about, then delete the DANGER.README file and try again.